# Cisco RV340 2 ISP IP Addresses

Tags: networking, router, dns, ip, isp

I have a modem from my ISP set to bridge. In order to compensate for any changes that might happen in my IP allocation from my ISP I am using a Dynamic DNS which I update from the router itself.

When I update the Dynamic DNS from the router, I see that it updates with the same IP address that the router is receiving from the modem via the DHCP setting. However, when I try to see my ip address via a website like whatismyip.com, I see a completely different IP address and not one that is even close to the one I am seeing in the router. Therefore, if I try and update my dynamic DNS from a process on my laptop, it is updating with a completely different IP address. This constant changing of IP address updating to the dynamic DNS is making problems when trying to access systems like cameras or intercom from outside because it is almost like one of these external IP addresses are not real.

I called the ISP and they are convinced that this issue is one which the router is meant to handle. That the router is meant to be able to synchronize between these two addresses and handle both traffic cases. Does this make sense? If so, how is my router meant to handle these two addresses? At the moment the WAN is set to DHCP mode and is taking all IP and DNS information from the cable modem set to bridge mode.

Comment: At least tell us the first half of each IP address

Comment: the IP address I am seeing in my router from the ISP is 100.94.xxx.xxx and the IP I am seeing when I go to an external side is 77.137.xxx.xxx

Comment: Some of the 100.x.x.x is CGNAT, but I'm not certain exactly how much of it.

Comment: Right I read about that. Is there a way for me to account for that from within or can it only be handled on the ISP end? I also figure that I would have to speak to someone at the ISP who actually knows what they are talking about....

Comment: See https://superuser.com/search?q=cgnat more many similar questions - buying a fixed address or setting up a VPN seem to be the common routes.

Comment: Thanks, I got them to take me out of CGNAT. Now I can use Dynamic DNS to handle changing IP's. Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 1):

The issue was being put into CGNAT by my ISP. Soon as I got them to take me out of the CGNAT and route my IP address directly to my house, I was able to use Dynamic DNS to handle any IP address changes I might experience.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).